# Standard List Controller Pagination Problem

Tags: visualforce, pagination

I have this simple VF page using standard contact list controller.
The problem is when I click **Next »** for the first time - it is display me the same first page. Only following click shows me second page.

I'm on free dev account.

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" recordSetVar="contacts">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="Contact List" id="contacts_list">
            Filter: 
            <apex:selectList value="{! filterId }" size="1">
                <apex:selectOptions value="{! listViewOptions }"/>
                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="contacts_list"/>
            </apex:selectList>
            <apex:pageBlockTable title="Contacts" value="{!contacts}" var="c">
                <apex:column value="{!c.Name}" />
                <apex:column value="{!c.Email}" />
                <apex:column value="{!c.Account.Name}" />
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
            <table style="width:100%">
                <td align="left"><apex:outputText >Page {! PageNumber } of {! CEILING(ResultSize/PageSize) }</apex:outputText></td>
                <td align="center">
                    <apex:commandLink action="{! previous }" value="« Previous" rendered="{! hasPrevious }" />
                    <apex:outputText style="color:#ccc" value="« Previous" rendered="{! NOT(hasPrevious) }" />
                    &nbsp;
                    <apex:commandLink action="{! next }" value="Next »" rendered="{! hasNext }" />
                    <apex:outputText style="color:#ccc" value="Next »" rendered="{! NOT(hasNext) }" />
                </td>
                <td align="right">
                    Records per page:
                    <apex:selectList value="{! PageSize }" size="1">
                        <apex:selectOption itemValue="5" itemLabel="5" />
                        <apex:selectOption itemValue="10" itemLabel="10" />
                        <apex:selectOption itemValue="20" itemLabel="20" />
                        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="contacts_list" />
                    </apex:selectList>
                </td>
            </table>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: @sfdcweb There is no custom controller; appears to be an example of [Pagination and the StandardSetController – No Custom Controller Required](https://saramorgan.net/2014/11/11/pagination-and-the-standardsetcontroller-no-custom-controller-required/).

Comment: @KeithC  ohh i didn't notice that..

Comment: Actually I took this from [trailhead](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en/visualforce_fundamentals/visualforce_standard_list_controllers)